# QEMU+KVM: Two errors after running virsh list --all, seems to be permission error

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

after running `virsh list --all`, I get the following errors:

```
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied
```

This is what I get after running `ls -la /var/run/libvirt/`:

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root     380 Jan 19 20:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 40 root root    1100 Jan 19 20:28 ..
drwx------  2 root root      60 Jan 19 20:28 common
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      40 Jan 19 20:28 hostdevmgr
drwx------  2 root root      60 Jan 19 20:28 interface
srw-------  1 root root       0 Jan 19 20:28 libvirt-admin-sock
srw-rw----  1 root libvirt    0 Jan 19 20:28 libvirt-sock
srw-rw-rw-  1 root root       0 Jan 19 20:28 libvirt-sock-ro
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     140 Jan 19 20:28 network
drwx------  2 root root      60 Jan 19 20:28 nodedev
drwx------  2 root root      60 Jan 19 20:28 nwfilter
drwx------  2 root root      40 Jan 19 20:28 nwfilter-binding
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     120 Jan 19 20:28 qemu
drwx------  2 root root      60 Jan 19 20:28 secrets
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      80 Jan 19 20:28 storage
srw-------  1 root root       0 Jan 19 20:28 virtlockd-admin-sock
srw-------  1 root root       0 Jan 19 20:28 virtlockd-sock
srw-------  1 root root       0 Jan 19 20:28 virtlogd-admin-sock
srw-------  1 root root       0 Jan 19 20:28 virtlogd-sock
```

Answer (score 1):

On install of libvirt users which are allowed to use `sudo` are added to the `libvirt` group, those can access the socket. Everyone else is considered non-privileged.

If you are on a user that didn't exist back then or was not in the sudoers group you will not yet have a group membership of libvirt. You can check that by running `id` which should list `... groups=...,129(libvirt)` (the numer can vary).

If you are not, then you need to add yourself (or ask an admin to do so) to that group.

Something like `sudo usermod -a -G libvirt <youruser>` should do that.